# Alberto Uderzo RIP: fantasy (Getafix and his magic potion) and laughter were his gifts

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

I read in the news today that at the age of 92, Alberto Uderzo passed away from a heart attack.  He and René Goscinny brought us Astérix and Obélix, those zany and funny Gauls, and a variety of Roman officials like *Nebulus Nimbus*: all victims of bad Latin.

[image]
Source = a German magazine, Der Spiegel (and it appears, Charlie Hebdo).

Please raise a glass or a smile to the man who drew them all: Alberto Aleandro Uderzo.  A Frenchman of Italian ancestry.

We first read his books in 1969, and I've been laughing at them ever since. And so have my kids.

Comment: Astérix was probably the first comic I loved. R.I.P. Uderzo...